# How to position a shape using x and y coordinates in java graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, polygon

I'm trying to reposition the red hexagon to the center of the rectangle pointed to by the black arrow in the image below.

[image: I want to move the hexagon to the center]

I can't find where to put the x and y coordinates though.

```
public void poligon(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Polygon pol;

    int x[] = {375, 400, 450, 475, 450, 400};
    int y[] = {150, 100, 100, 150, 200, 200};

    pol = new Polygon(x, y, x.length);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
    g2d.fill(pol);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your hexagon looks above and to the left of the position you would like it centered. Thus, **add** the same amount to every integer in `x[]` and **subtract** the same amount from every integer in `y[]`. The integers in those arrays represent the x and y coordinates of your hexagon's vertices.

I would just try random amounts narrowing down the exact amount to add and subtract. For instance, at a glance it looks like you need to add 100 to `x[]` and subtract 20 from `y[]`. You could either hard code the values:

```
int x[] = {375 + 100, 400 + 100, 450 + 100, 475 + 100, 450 + 100, 400 + 100};
int y[] = {150 - 20, 100 - 20, 100 - 20, 150 - 20, 200 - 20, 200 - 20};
```

Or you could save some time narrowing down the values and just run a loop:

```
public void poligon(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Polygon pol;

    // the x and y coordinates of the vertices of your hexagon
    int x[] = {375, 400, 450, 475, 450, 400};
    int y[] = {150, 100, 100, 150, 200, 200};

    // how much to offset the x and y coordinates by
    int xOffset = 100;
    int yOffset = 20;

    // offset your hexagon until you narrow down the right position
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
        x[i] += xOffset;
        y[i] -= yOffset;
    }

    pol = new Polygon(x, y, x.length);
    g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
    g2d.fill(pol);
}
```

Note: There are much simpler ways to calculate the center coordinates, but with the code you provided this is the only solution I could provide.

Comment: srry i cant give you rep yet

Answer (score 1):

I think you always put in your example x and y coordinates to make the Polygon.
In your example x positions on the points of the polygon are: 375, 400, 450, 475, 450, 400 and the y positions of the same points are 150, 100, 100, 150, 200, 200.

I would try to find the difference between the points and save it. In your example you can get 375 as base for x. So the point inside the array will be:

```
int baseX = 375;
int x[] = {baseX, baseX + 25, baseX + 75, baseX + 100, baseX + 75, baseX + 25};
```

Please do the same thing for y. After that experiment with the base of baseX and baseY. This way you will not broke your polygon and you can safely move it around.

Have a great time coding!